# Компиляция python3 проекта в один исполняемый (.exe) фай

Tags: python-3.x, компиляция, exe, library, cx-freeze

Здравствуйте! 
Цель и вопрос: Скомпилировать python3 проект в один исполняемый(.exe) файл. 
Я уже использовал cx_Freeze и собирал проект с его помощью, но он рядом с exe создает файлы со всеми необходимыми для работы библиотеками 
Но я хочу чтобы абсолютно всё было в одном .exe файле
Найти другой способ мне не удавалось

Возможно я мало знаю про cx_Freeze и не внимательно искал, но буду очень благодарен если вы мне расскажете как можно реализвать мне это используя его или что то другое!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Установите pyinstaller**

**pip install pyinstaller**

**Виндовс командная строка**

**pyinstaller ваш_скрипт.py --onefile**